# How to mark as selected first element of a list on app load?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of radio items and I want on app load to set first element as selected.
At the moment no item is selected.
This is my code for radio item

```
    Expanded(
            child: RadioListTile(
              dense: true,
              title: Text(titleItemName,
                  style:
                  getCustomStyle(color:gray)
              ),
              value: value,
              groupValue: groupValue,
              onChanged: onChanged,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: As here you've only include single `RadioListTile`, Can you include full widget and also check the Wiktor's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html) along with code example. You just simply need variable for `groupdValue` with default value set on stage of widget build.